# Calculator console app not working

Tags: java, console-application

I'm trying to make a simple calculator console app. The answer stays 0 no matter what I do. Can anyone tell me what is wrong if anything is wrong without giving me a direct answer.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int firstNum;
        int secondNum;
        int division = 0, addition = 0, subtraction = 0, multiplication = 0;
        String userChoice = "";
        String choices[] = {"add","multiply","divide","subtract"};

        System.out.print("Please enter first number: ");
        firstNum = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please enter second number: ");
        secondNum = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("What type of operation would you like to perform?");
        System.out.println("add, multiply, subtract or divide.");
        input.nextLine();
        userChoice = input.nextLine();

        if (userChoice.equals("add"))
        System.out.print("The answer is " + addition);
        else if (userChoice.equals("multiply"))
        System.out.print("The answer is " + multiplication);
        else if (userChoice.equals("subtract"))
        System.out.print("The answer is " + subtraction);
        else if (userChoice.equals("divide"))
        System.out.print("The answer is " + division);

        division = firstNum / secondNum;
        addition = firstNum + secondNum;
        subtraction = firstNum - secondNum;
        multiplication = firstNum * secondNum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well look at where you're printing out the result, vs where you're actually changing the values of `division`, `addition` etc... (It's not clear why you need those variables at all - why not just print `"The answer is " + (firstNum + secondNum)` etc? Or have a *single* result variable which is set in the if/else part, then `System.out.println("The answer is " + answer");`

Comment: Thanks! That helped. Works like a charm now.

Comment: Computers are dump, they do what you tell them in the exact order you tell them.

Comment: *"so I should swap the 'if' statements and the "calculator formulae"?"* no, you should do the calculation before the output.

Answer (score 2):

As others have already said, the calculation needs to be done before the output.

I suggest some more improvements:

1. Use proper variable naming. For example, `addition` is an operation but the variable holds the result of this operation which is usually called `sum`. So use these names for your variables. Actually, you don't need four different variables, see below.
2. Declare your variables where you need them, not at the beginning of the function.
3. In your code, the four possible calculations are always performed, not only the one selected by the user.

The second part of your code (after the input) could look like this:

```
    int result = 0;
    if (userChoice.equals("add")) {
        result = firstNum + secondNum;
    }
    else if (userChoice.equals("subtract")) {
        result = firstNum - secondNum;
    } 
    else if (userChoice.equals("multiply")) {
        result = firstNum * secondNum;
    } 
    else if (userChoice.equals("divide")) {
        // maybe check if secondNum is not zero
        result = firstNum / secondNum;
    }
    else {
        System.out.print("Invalid input " + userChoice);
        return;
    }

    System.out.print("The answer is " + result);
```